# I don't understand where does the $\frac{k-1}{k}$ factor come from, in the probability mass function derived by Bayesian approach.

Tags: estimation, bayesian

I don't understand where does the $\frac{k-1}{k}$ factor come from, in the probability mass function derived by Bayesian approach:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

(in the Example section, near the top of the article)

Answer (score 0):

It's derived later on in the same article, in the "Summation Formula" subsection.

Comment: Hmm, now I am even more confused. Can you please explain to me the whole formula int the mass function, i.e. what does each term represent, where does it come from? I thought I understood the rest of it without the (k-1)  / k part: numerator is with m maximum, denomiator is all possible combos, but now I don't follow it any more.

Comment: @BaronYugovich The Wikipedia article does a better job than I could, I think (look in the "Many Tanks" section). As far as I can tell, you're correct about where the numerator and denominator come from, given a particular value of $n$; the extra $\frac{k-1}k$ term comes from summing that fraction over all possible values of $n$.